# when url is 'abc' ajax is working and when urs is 'abc/2' ajax is not working in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
<script>


  $(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).on('change','#compId',function () {


                var username = $(this).val();
                /*var token =  $("input[name=_token]").val();
                var dataString = 'username='+username+'&token='+token; 
                */
                var data1={username}

                $.ajax({
                    type: "get",
                    url : 'depttBranch',
                    data : data1,

                    success : function(data){
                     $('#branchId').html(data);
                     alert(data);

                    },error : function(){
                        alert('out');
                    }
                });

          });
});//end of document ready function


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using a [relative URL](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html), `depttBranch`.

This means that on `http://example.com/abc` the relative URL `depttBranch` will make an absolute URL `http://example.com/abc/depttBranch` while on `http://example.com/abc/2` it will make `http://example.com/abc/2/depttBranch`.

Therefore you have to use some kind of more exact specification in the URL, for example relative to the root, e.g. `/abc/depttBranch`. This way it will always be `http://example.com/abc/depttBranch`.